# Loaded into GNU GRUB after deleting Ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, grub

[image]
After deleting my Ubuntu disk partition, I was brought here. I understand that was not the right way to go about getting rid of it, but that is not the problem. How can I boot back into windows reliably?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by booting from Windows installation DVD, press F8, go to recovery options and get a command line. There tool called `bootrec.exe` will help you.